# Работа с контурами opencv

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На изображении один объект, после него будут еще объекты, допустим еще 10 таких, все они проедут за 1 минуту. На выходе эти 10 объектов должны появиться одновременно или друг за другом и в итоге видос будет не 1 минуту а 10 секунд.
Для этого надо для каждого контура создать маску. Будет в итоге 10 масок, и их одновременно наложить. Как записывать маску каждого контура в отдельный массив и заканчивать запись, когда объект проехал? или есть другой путь?

Comment: [контур в opencv](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html) *уже* отдельным numpy массивом является.

Comment: вы можете уточнить вопрос? приведите небольшие примеры входных данных и того, что хотите получить на выходе. пока не совсем понятно что именно у вас не получается

Comment: @jfs, именно сам контур это лист индексов, а когда его выводим то это np массив формы изображения, если я правильно понимаю

Comment: @MaxU, Поправил))

Comment: по-моему проще просто удалить все статические (не содержащие интересующих объектов) кадры

Comment: @MaxU, это тоже присутствует в коде, из 500 кадров, всего 99 кадров где нет объектов, а на выходе объекты все ровно появляются с обычной частотой. Этого не достаточно, они должны появиться почти одновременно, пусть даже наложатся на друг друга но сама идея